# grep nth string from a very large file in constant time(file size independent)?

Tags: regex, bash, sed, grep, large-files

Is there a grep (sed/awk) like tool in linux to find the nth occurrence of a string(regex) from a very large file? Also, I would like to find the number of occurrences of the search string within the file. Remember, the file is really large (> 2 gb).

Comment: File size independent? I very much doubt it. Fast enough for your needs? Quite possibly. What is your desired output? Show us an example, preferably much closer to 2Kb.

Comment: What difference would `nth occurrence` and `total occurrence` make? This question is underspecified at the moment. Please address what kind of string? Does the string contains spaces and so on?

Comment: Which do you want to find - a string or a regexp? Are partial matches acceptable? What should the output be - a line number, or a line, or the matching text or something else? [edit] your question to provide that plus all of the other missing information that would help us to help solve your problem, including concise, testable sample input and expected output.

Comment: How could it possibly be independent of the filesize? If you have an 80GB file that you can read at 80MB/s it is necessarily going to take 1,000 seconds if the Nth occurrence is at the end of the file and a lot less if it is on the first line.

Comment: I'm trying to find the distribution of a regex string in large datafiles which would help me distinguish between random vs. systematic spread of the string within the file. This is very useful to find the statistical distribution of a signal string in a very large sensor data file. For example the distribution of line separation of the world "climate" in the wikipedia climate change article is at median value of 3 and stdev of 9. The real problem is doing the same with very large files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Grep solution:

`grep -on regexp < file.txt`

### file.txt:

> one two one
>
> two
>
> one
>
> two two
>
> two one

#### Lines with regexp **one**

`grep -on one < test.txt`

> 1:one
>
> 1:one
>
> 3:one
>
> 5:one

#### How many occurrences:

`grep -on one < test.txt | wc -l`

> 4

#### Line with the Nth occurrence:

`grep -m1 one < test.txt | tail -n1`

> one two one

**Update:** Now, the solutions don't use `cat`. Thanks to @tripleee for the hint.

Comment: Most of the answers are correct  however a very large file support solution would be very helpful to process large data fast. I was enquiring if there is some kind of one time indexing scheme that can augment the grep (or its likes) search really fast for large files.

Comment: mmm... Maybe you can use bigger block size and improve the results... Or you can use a RAM filesystem like tmpfs... Or use a faster media (SSD vs HDD)...

Comment: Great suggestion and yes SSD/HDD make it much better but still not a perfectly scalable solution.

Comment: That's a [useless use of `cat`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html).  Especially for a question where speed is a factor in the solution, this is a wasteful antipattern.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to find the number of occurrences of the search string
>   within the file

If the search string can't contain spaces, below might suffice:

```
awk -v RS=" " '/string/{i++}END{print "string count : " i}' file
```

But how fast it would be depends on the available RAM on the system.

Comment: This works for total occurrences. Thanks!